# lldb debugger shows type-qualifier const in string literal type. Is this a bug in lldb?

Tags: c, gdb, lldb

In C, the type of a string literal is `char []`.

`gdb` debugger:

```
(gdb) ptype ""
type = char [1]
(gdb) ptype "abc"
type = char [4]
```

`lldb` debugger:

```
(lldb) p ""
(const char [1]) $0 = ""
(lldb) p "abc"
(const char [4]) $1 = "abc"
```

The `gdb` debugger shows type of string literal as `char [N]` (which is as per language standard) but `lldb` debugger shows `const` type-qualifier in string literal type - `const char [N]`.
Is this a bug in `lldb` debugger? Or, am I missing something?

Comment: In C++ the type of a string literal is `const char[N]`. Does the debugger have any way of differentiating the language you intend to refer to?

Comment: @user17732522: `expr -l c -- "abc"` produces the same output. (My LLDB claims to be version “Apple Swift version 5.1.3”.)

Comment: AFAICS, gdb reports that the type of a string literal is `char [N]`, even after `set language c++`. (I don't find that surprising, though. Any more than the fact that LLDB prefers C++.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the `lldb` debugger uses ISO `C++` rules/specifications while evaluating an expression given to the `print` command and in `C++` the type of ordinary string literal is `const char[N]`, where `N` is the size of the string including the null terminator.

Proof of `lldb` debugger uses ISO `C++` rules/specifications:

Assume a C program has a variable definition:

```
    int x;
```

While debugging this program using `lldb` debugger, if I do:

```
(lldb) p sizeof (*(void *)&x)
error: expression failed to parse:
warning: <user expression 4>:1:9: ISO C++ does not allow indirection on operand of type 'void *'
sizeof (*(void *)&x)
        ^~~~~~~~~~~
error: <user expression 4>:1:8: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'void'
sizeof (*(void *)&x)
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

In the error, it says `ISO C++ ..`.
This proves that `lldb` debugger uses `C++` language rules/specifications to evaluate an expression given to `print` command. Hence, `lldb` debugger shows type `const char [4]` in the output of command `p "abc"`.

---

Additional:

In `gdb` debugger, we can set the current source language using `set language` command:

```
(gdb) show language
The current source language is "auto; currently c".

(gdb) set language c++
Warning: the current language does not match this frame.

(gdb) show language
The current source language is "c++".
Warning: the current language does not match this frame.

(gdb) ptype "abc"
type = char [4]
```

Even after setting `language` to `c++` the output showing `type` as `char [4]`. It may be because `set language` command only set the current source language but while evaluating the expressions given to `print` command, it might be using `C` language rules.

I did not find anything similar in `lldb` debugger to set/reset source language during debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal):

"String literals are **not modifiable** (and in fact may be placed in read-only memory such as .rodata). If a program attempts to modify the static array formed by a string literal, the behavior is undefined."

`lldb` is just showing the type of the real memory under the hood even though it's formally reachable through a pointer to const.